# c++ linked list pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault for the code below when the program reaches addnode() function. So I don't know if there would be any issues elsewhere since the flow is not going forward

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int value;
    node *next;
};
node *head;
void addnode(int);
void destroytree();
int main()
{
    head=new node;
    head=NULL;
    int no,ch=1;
    while(ch!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Choice (0 exit, 1 enter): ";
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch==0) break;
        cout<<"Enter no: ";
        cin>>no;
        addnode(no);
    }
    cout<<"\nTime to print.\n\n";
    destroytree();
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void addnode(int no)
{
    node *n=new node;
    node *trav;
    trav=head;
    while(trav!=NULL && trav->next!=NULL)
    {
        trav=trav->next;
    }
    if(trav==NULL)
    {
        trav->value=no;
        trav->next=NULL;
        return;
    }
    n->value=no;
    n->next=NULL;
    trav->next=n;
}
void destroytree()
{
    node *n;
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        n=head;
        cout<<head->value<<"->NEXT **   ";
        head=head->next;
        delete n;
    }
}
```

Classes are not allowed. I want 'head' to point to start of the list in all cases except destroytree(). To add a node to the end of the list, start from the 'head' and move on till next is NULL. To destroy the tree, print the first element then delete it. Print the next element and delete it till node->next is NULL

Comment: If you had tried to find a [mcve] you would have discovered your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing a null pointer which doesn't make sense.
You are also repeating yourself in the code below so maybe you're not thinking through what you're doing.

```
if(trav==NULL)
{
    trav->value=no;
    trav->next=NULL;
    return;
}
n->value=no;
n->next=NULL;
trav->next=n;
```

Apart from assigning the values to the node, all you're looking to do is drop the new node into the end of the list. If you didn't find that by traversing the list it's because the list is empty so the end of the list is the head.

```
n->value=no;
n->next=NULL;
(trav != NULL ? trav->next : head) = n;
```

Comment: By the way, I would assign the values to the new node first before adding it to the list, in fact as close as possible to where the new node is allocated. That way you're not leaving junk data lying around the place. Makes it easier when you are debugging, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
head=new node;
head=NULL;        // Remove this line
```

After you assign `new` allocated memory to `head`, you overwrite it with `null` and trying to dereference it.

---

Also here, you would dereference `NULL` pointer as well

```
if(trav==NULL)
{
    trav->value=no;
    trav->next=NULL;
    return;
}
```

Since it is redundant you should remove it and use following

```
n->value=no;
n->next=NULL;
n = (trav != NULL ? trav->next : head);
```

---

`nullptr` is of pointer type , while `NULL` has the tendency to be integer, so please, in `C++11` and higher use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(trav==NULL)
{
    trav->value=no;
    trav->next=NULL;
    return;
}
```

You are trying to dereference a null pointer.
Remove that piece of code, and add the following to the beginning of addnode:

```
if(head == NULL)
{
    head = new node;
    head->value = no;
    head->next = NULL;
    return;
 }
```

This also allows you to remove the `trav == NULL` from the `while` loop condition.

Also note that in main you have

```
head=new node;
head=NULL;
```

So you are allocating memory for a node, then you are dropping the only reference you have to that memory address.
You should remove the first of those, and you can replace the assignment of head to `NULL` to the definition of head (the line that reads `node *head;`, replace it with `node *head = NULL;`)

Lastly, if you have a c++11 compliant compiler, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: If `head` is `NULL`, and you don't assign to it(as it is in his code), then it will stay `NULL`. Unless you are assuming `head` must be initialized to a valid pointer elsewhere before the first call to `addnode`

Comment: But before that condition you are assigning head `trav=head;` to trav which you are checking for NULL.

Comment: And in his code, when he finds `if(trav == NULL)`, instead of assigning the new node to `head`, he attempts to dereference `trav`, which is `NULL`.

Comment: Yes thats wrong. But ive meant something else. Let it be